# Solving $2\cos\left(2\theta\right) = \sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question on this test review problem (that will help us on a test), and I have no clue what it's asking. We're learning trigonometry, (Analytic Trigonometry), like about the unit circle, inverse trig functions, etc... And I encounter this problem on test review:

> $$ 2\cos\left(2\theta\right) =  \sqrt{3}$$

I know the answers are: $\left\{\frac{\pi}{12}, \frac{11\pi}{12}, \frac{13\pi}{12}, \frac{23\pi}{12} \right\} $

But I want to know how to find it. So I get ready for test. Thank you.

### EDIT

After some thinking i got some of it but not All!! So what i did was:

$ 2\Theta = \cos^{-1} (\frac{\sqrt3}{2} )$

$2\Theta = \frac {\pi}{6}$

$\Theta = \frac{\pi}{12} + 2\pi n$

So now i just add 2pi but i have to remember $0 \le  \Theta \lt 2\pi$

I get:

$\left\{\frac{\pi}{12}, \frac{13\pi}{12} \right\} $ But that obviously isnt the anwser.. Please help!

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ should be recognisable as coming from half an equilateral triangle, so is the cosine of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and various related angles which are possible values of $2\theta$.  If $0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi$, you want to find the related angles such that $0 \le 2\theta \lt 4\pi$

Comment: Huh @Henry ? You sound like my math teacher now :P

Comment: Here's an [answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1295976/120540) to a similar question, that uses the technique @Henry is describing.

Comment: This question does NOT deserve upvotes. The quality of MSE is going down..

Comment: You forgot that $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This writes as $\;\cos2\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt 3}2=\cos\dfrac\pi6$. Now you have to know that

- $\cos x=\cos\alpha\iff\theta\equiv\pm\alpha\pmod2\pi$, and similarly:
- $\sin  x=\sin \alpha\iff\begin{cases}\theta\equiv\alpha\pmod{2\pi},\\\theta\equiv\pi-\alpha\pmod{2\pi},
  \end{cases}$
- $\tan x=\tan\alpha\iff x\equiv\alpha\pmod\pi.$

So here, you have
$$2\theta\equiv \pm\frac\pi6\pmod{2\pi}\iff \theta\equiv\frac\pi{12}\pmod{\pi}$$
If you want the solutions in $[0,2\pi]$, you get
$$\theta =\frac\pi{12},-\frac\pi{12}+\pi=\frac{11\pi}{12},\frac\pi{12}+\pi=\frac{13\pi}{12},-\frac\pi{12}+2\pi=\frac{23\pi}{12}.$$

Comment: We never, learned about the equation you use... mod $$2 \pi$$ ??

Comment: @AmanuelBogale Essentially that is saying $$2\theta = 2n\pi \pm \frac\pi 6$$ for integers $n$.

Comment: That's congruence, as in arithmetic, a very handy way to express solutions. Explicitly, $\theta\equiv\dfrac\pi{12}\pmod{\pi}$ means there exists an integer $k$ such that $\theta =\dfrac\pi{12}+k\pi$. So all we have to do is to draw up the list of those elements which are in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: ?? I am soo confused now @peterwhy , Bernard..

Comment: @Bernard i understand some part of it now.. But i didnt understand the rest. I will edit my question. Please Explain me what i am doing wrong when i edit the question so i can get a good grade on test. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ok i edited question @peterwhy and Bernard. Please Help! I got some of it but not all!

Comment: Ok guys... Forget my last comment. I Understand now! Thanks a bunch for this!

Answer (score 1):

I would reform the equation $2\cos 2\theta = \sqrt{3}$ into $$\cos 2\theta \ =\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

For now, I wouldn't worry about the $2\theta$ because if $\theta$ is an angle, then so is $2\theta$, so my intermediary strategy is to find $2\theta$. Later I can always divide that number by 2.

So lets fund $2\theta$.
I'm looking for a triangle that has an adjacent side of $\sqrt 3$ and a hypotenuse of $2$. If I take an  equilateral triangle, and split it in half, I will have such a triangle.
[image]

So I know that that the angle that I'm looking for is $30^\circ$, or $\frac{\pi}{6}$ rads. In other words, $2\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$, solving for $\theta$ we have $\theta = \frac{\pi}{12}$.

Now that you have your reference angle all figured out, try to figure out what quadrants will give you a positive cosine. I think that you will find that the angles are $\theta = (2\pi)n\pm\frac{\pi}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the included picture will help you understand the solutions.[image]. The figure shows $\cos \theta$ in the range $-2 \pi \le \theta \le 2 \pi$. The blue line is the value $\cos \frac{\pi}{12}$ and you can see that it cuts the curve at four values in the request range. It's difficult to make out the required solutions (but you know them anyway), but it may help you understand whey there are four answers.

Comment: Hmm.. Im confused.. Can you show me in an algeberaic form like i did above jim? Like i got two out of the four values... but not all..

Comment: Nvm i had to rethink it.. Thanks i understand!

Answer (score 0):

we have $\cos \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}2$. Hence your equation reads
$$  \cos 2\theta = \cos \frac{\pi}{6}$$
then $$2\theta = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi \ \ \mbox{ or }  2\theta = -\frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (k\in\mathbb{Z})$$
that is 
$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{12} + k\pi \ \ \mbox{ or }  \theta = -\frac{\pi}{12} + k\pi \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (k\in\mathbb{Z})$$

It is clear that there are an infinite number of solution not only 4. (But if you precise an appropriate interval for solutions, you can make it to have those solutions in your question  )